# How to fix this elimination transformation in XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have this input:

```
<root>
    <sector>
        <nodeA id="a">
            <section id="i">
                <item1 id="1" method="delete"/>

                <item1 id="1" method="create"> 
                    <somechild>a</somechild>
                </item1>
                <item1 id="1" method="change"> 
                    <somechild>a</somechild>
                </item1>
            </section>
            <section id="i">
                <item1 id="1" method="change"> 
                    <somechild>a</somechild>
                </item1>
            </section>
            <section id="i">
                <item1 id="1" method="delete"/>
                <item1 id="1" method="create">
                    <somechild>a</somechild>
                </item1>
            </section>
        </nodeA>
    </sector> 
</root>
```

My XSL is:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="*[not(.//*[@id!=''])][@method='delete']">
        <xsl:if test="not(following::*[not(.//*[@id!=''])][@id=current()/@id][../@id = current()/../@id][generate-id(../..) = generate-id(current()/../..)])"/>       
    </xsl:template>    

    <xsl:template match="*[not(.//*[@id!=''])][@method!='delete']">
        <xsl:if test="not(following::*[not(.//*[@id!=''])][@method='delete'][@id=current()/@id][../@id = current()/../@id][generate-id(../..) = generate-id(current()/../..)])"/>
    </xsl:template>    

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()" name="identity">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My output:

```
<root>
    <sector>
        <nodeA id="a">
            <section id="i">
            </section>
            <section id="i">
            </section>
            <section id="i">
            </section>
        </nodeA>
    </sector>
</root>
```

**Expected Output:**

```
<root>
    <sector>
        <nodeA id="a">
            <section id="i">
                <item1 id="1" method="delete"/> <!-- leave this node -->
            </section>
            <section id="i">
            </section>
            <section id="i">
                <item1 id="1" method="create"> <!-- leave this node -->
                    <somechild>a</somechild>
                </item1>
            </section>
        </nodeA>
    </sector> 
</root>
```

The idea is that I want to **remove** a combination of element node with

- **one** method create followed by **one or more** modify followed by **one** delete method and leave the rest untouched.
- It has to be the same element name for example `<item1>` and `@id` and under the same parent for example `<section id=1>`.

Could anyone help me with the transformation ?

Thanks.
John

Comment: your questions get more and more trickier :)

Answer (score 1):

John, I have a solution that you may or may not like. I made one "optimization" to simplify things a bit. I figured that since you are treating those `section` nodes with the same `@id` as the *same*, you might as well don't mind seeing them all merged into one in the result document. See if this is acceptable.

The following **XSLT 2.0** transformation:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()" name="identity">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="nodeA">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-by="concat(name(), '|', @id)">
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
                    <xsl:variable name="merged">
                        <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()/*"
                                            group-by="concat(name(), '|', @id)">
                            <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
                        </xsl:for-each-group>
                    </xsl:variable>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="$merged/*"/>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[@method = 'create']
                          [following-sibling::*[@method = 'change']
                                               [following-sibling::*[@method = 'delete']]]"/>
    <xsl:template match="*[@method = 'change']
                          [preceding-sibling::*[@method = 'create']]
                          [following-sibling::*[@method = 'delete']]"/>

    <xsl:template match="*[@method = 'delete']
                          [preceding-sibling::*[@method = 'change']
                                               [preceding-sibling::*[@method = 'create']]]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

when applied to your input document produces:

```
<root>
    <sector>
      <nodeA id="a">
         <section id="i">
            <item1 id="1" method="delete"/>
            <item1 id="1" method="create">
                    <somechild>a</somechild>
                </item1>
         </section>
      </nodeA>
    </sector>
</root>
```

I figured that it would be much easier to collapse those `item1` nodes into a flat ordered list and only then filter out the sequence you want removed. I had to copy them into a variable to "detach" from the original document tree as otherwise those `sibling` axes would be looking within the original parent node. Once you have a flat list of "same" `item1` nodes from the "same" parent, filtering the create-change-delete sequence is really a piece of cake. I just translated your rules straight into XPath predicates - one for `create` followed by `change` followed by a `delete`, another one for `change` preceded by `create` and followed by a `delete`, and last one for `delete` preceded by `change` preceded by `create`. They all are "known" to be of the same `name()` and `@id` and coming from the same (`name()` and `@id`) parent so we don't have to check that part.

Comment: Thank you for the solutions. I'm still trying to implement this to match my bigger xml input. I'll get back to you. Thanks once again

Answer (score 1):

well it was not easy, but it works in xslt 1.0!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
<!--
    copies all nodes with id
    if there first preceding delete followed by the first preceding create
    -->
    <xsl:template match="*[not(.//*[@id!=''])]">
        <xsl:variable name="id" select="@id"/>
        <xsl:variable name="parentId" select="../@id"/>
        <xsl:variable name="precedings" select="preceding::*[@id=$id][../@id=$parentId]"/>
        <xsl:variable name="lastDelete" select="($precedings[@method='delete'])[last()]"/>
        <xsl:variable name="lastCreate" select="($precedings[@method='create'])[last()]"/>
        <xsl:variable name="openCreate" select="$lastDelete[following::* = $lastCreate] or (not($lastDelete) and $lastCreate)"/>
        <xsl:if test="not(following::*[@id=$id][../@id=$parentId][@method='delete'] and $openCreate)">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

    <!--
    copies all deletes, if they have no preceding creates
    -->
    <xsl:template match="*[not(.//*[@id!=''])][@method='delete']" priority="10">
        <xsl:variable name="id" select="@id"/>
        <xsl:variable name="parentId" select="../@id"/>
        <xsl:variable name="precedings" select="preceding::*[@id=$id][../@id=$parentId]"/>
        <xsl:variable name="precCreate" select="$precedings[@method='create']"/>
        <xsl:if test="not($precCreate)">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

<!--
    copies all creates, if they have no following deletes
    -->

    <xsl:template match="*[not(.//*[@id!=''])][@method='create']" priority="10">
        <xsl:variable name="id" select="@id"/>
        <xsl:variable name="parentId" select="../@id"/>
        <xsl:variable name="followings" select="following::*[@id=$id][../@id=$parentId]"/>
        <xsl:variable name="followDelete" select="$followings[@method='delete']"/>
        <xsl:if test="not($followDelete)">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

    <!--
        copies all nodes
    -->
    <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

test it... without guarantee!

Comment: it works, however it's missing one requirement I believe. Those `item1` nodes that are `[@id = $id]` should also belong to the "same" parent to be eligible for "merge". something like `[parent::*/@id = (current()/parent::*/@id)]` will need to be added to those `[@id = $id]` predicates.

Comment: I then played with various combination of `create`-`change`-`delete` sequences and results were not matching John's requirements. I guess your transform needs some more testing and tweaking but you're definitely onto something here.

Comment: ok, i made some changes: i misunderstood the second requirement, i fixed that. Also there was some bugs.